# Определять выход дочернего элемента за границы родителя? js (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

делаю многоуровневое меню (три уровня), столкнулся с проблемой, что у крайних пунктов, меню вторых третьих уровней выходят за зону видимости (и собственно за свой первоначальный родитель).

Можно это исправить тем же css, разными методами, но я подумал, если в дальнейшем например начать изменять контент в меню, это может вылезти боком.

Интересуюсь как  отслеживать когда какой либо `ul` с классом `.sub-menu` будет выходить за края (по ширине) родителя меню, и уже тогда динамически присваивать ему класс с нужными стилями которые будут разворачивать его в противоположную сторону.

Буду рад если поможете такое реализовать или подсказать.

```js
(function($) {
      var size;
   
    //SMALLER HEADER WHEN SCROLL PAGE
      function smallerMenu() {
          var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
          if (sc > 40) {
              $('#header-sroll').addClass('small');
          }else {
              $('#header-sroll').removeClass('small');
          }
      }


      // VERIFY WINDOW SIZE
      function windowSize() {
          size = $(document).width();
          if (size >= 991) {
              $('body').removeClass('open-menu');
              $('.hamburger-menu .bar').removeClass('animate');
          }
      };

       // ESC BUTTON ACTION
      $(document).keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 27) {
              $('.bar').removeClass('animate');
              $('body').removeClass('open-menu');
              $('header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu .menu-item-has-children a ul').each(function( index ) {
                  $(this).removeClass('open-sub');
              });
          }
      });

      $('#cd-primary-nav > li').hover(function() {
          $whidt_item = $(this).width();
          $whidt_item = $whidt_item-8;

          $prevEl = $(this).prev('li');
          $preWidth = $(this).prev('li').width();
          var pos = $(this).position();
          pos = pos.left+4;
          $('header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu>li.line').css({
              width:  $whidt_item,
              left: pos,
              opacity: 1
          });

          
      });

       // ANIMATE HAMBURGER MENU
      $('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
          $('.hamburger-menu .bar').toggleClass('animate');
          if($('body').hasClass('open-menu')){
              $('body').removeClass('open-menu');
          }else{
              $('body').toggleClass('open-menu');
          }
      });

      $('header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu .menu-item-has-children ul').each(function(index) {
          $(this).append('<li class="back"><a href="#">Voltar</a></li>');
      });

      // RESPONSIVE MENU NAVIGATION
      $('header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu .menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if(size <= 991){
              $(this).next('ul').addClass('open-sub');
          }
      });

      // CLICK FUNCTION BACK MENU RESPONSIVE
      $('header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu .menu-item-has-children ul .back').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent('ul').removeClass('open-sub');
      });

      $('body .over-menu').on('click', function() {
          $('body').removeClass('open-menu');
          $('.bar').removeClass('animate');
      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
          windowSize();
      });

      $(window).scroll(function(){
          smallerMenu();
      });

      $(window).resize(function(){
          windowSize();
      });

  })(jQuery);
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; overflow-x: hidden; color: #4e4e4e; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; position: relative; left: 0; } body > .over-menu { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; position: fixed; height: 100%; content: ''; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); z-index: 9; } body.open-menu { left: -250px; } body.open-menu > .over-menu { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; } body.open-menu .menu-container { right: 0 !important; } a { text-decoration: none !important; outline: none; } .hidden { display: none; } section { position: relative; width: 100%; float: left; } header { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; transition: all 0.3s ease; background-color: transparent; width: 100%; float: left; position: fixed; z-index: 10; } header::before { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; transition: all 0.3s ease; transform-origin: 0; background: #FFF; position: absolute; width: 100%; content: ''; top: 0; right: 0; height: 0; } header .desk-menu { position: relative; width: 100%; float: left; } header .desk-menu .logo { position: absolute; float: left; } header .desk-menu .logo-adn { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; margin: 20px 0 0; position: relative; display: table; z-index: 1; } header .desk-menu .logo-adn a { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; background-image: url(""); background-position: 0; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 0; } header .desk-menu .box-menu { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; position: relative; padding: 16px 0 0; display: block; margin: 0 auto; float: right; text-align: center; } header .desk-menu .menu-container { float: left; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head, header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot { width: 100%; float: left; display: none; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head { background: #4285f4; padding: 16px 10px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head .e1 { padding: 3px 0; float: left; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head .e1 img { width: 29px; float: left; height: 29px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head .client { color: #FFF; float: right; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head .client span { font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px 42px 5px  0; position: relative; line-height: 100%; font-size: 9px; display: block; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-head .client i { position: absolute; font-size: 30px; right: 0; top: 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot { position: absolute; bottom: 0; padding: 15px 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot .social { display: table; margin: 0 auto; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot .social a { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 0 5px 0 0; color: #FFF; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; padding: 5px 0; border-radius: 50%; background: #797c82; width: 29px; height: 29px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot .social a:last-child { margin: 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot .social a:hover { background: #a4a7ac; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot hr { margin: 15px auto 20px; display: table; width: calc(100% - 20px); } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot address { position: relative; text-align: left; padding: 0 15px; margin: 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot address i { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu-foot address span { padding: 0 0 0 20px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px; display: block; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu { float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0 20px 0 0; list-style: none; position: relative; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu li.back { display: none; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li { -webkit-transition: all 0.33s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.33s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.33s ease; -o-transition: all 0.33s ease; transition: all 0.33s ease; margin: 0 0 0 10px; float: left; cursor: pointer; position: relative; overflow: inherit; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li a { position: relative; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; font-size: 13.9px; padding: 19px 8px; display: block; color: #4e4e4e; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a { padding: 19px 20px 19px 8px; position: relative; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::before, header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; background-color: #4e4e4e; position: absolute; content: ''; height: 1px; width: 7px; top: 26px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::before { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -o-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg); right: 10px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after { -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg); right: 6px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu { box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.2); -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; min-width: 200px; position: absolute; list-style: none; background: #FFF; padding: 0; float: left; display: table; left: 0; width: 100%; float: left; display: none; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li { width: 100%; -webkit-transition: all 0.33s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.33s ease; -ms-transition: all 0.33s ease; -o-transition: all 0.33s ease; transition: all 0.33s ease; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li > a { color: #4e4e4e; padding: 12px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li .sub-menu, li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li .sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li .sub-menu { display: none; } /**/ .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li .sub-menu { display: none!important; } /**/ header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a::before, header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a::after { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; background-color: #4e4e4e; position: absolute; content: ''; height: 1px; width: 7px; top: 24px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a::before { transform: rotate(45deg); right: 6px; top: 19px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a::after { transform: rotate(-45deg); right: 6px; top: 23px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > a { display: block; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu { display: block; } /**/ header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > a { display: block!important; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu { display: block!important; } /**/ header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover > a { color: #4285f4; background-color: #eeeff1; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover > a::before { -webkit-transform: rotate(142deg); -moz-transform: rotate(142deg); -ms-transform: rotate(142deg); -o-transform: rotate(142deg); transform: rotate(142deg); top: 23px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover > a::after { -webkit-transform: rotate(42deg); -moz-transform: rotate(42deg); -ms-transform: rotate(42deg); -o-transform: rotate(42deg); transform: rotate(42deg); right: 11px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu { left: 100%; margin-top: -43px; } /**/ @media (min-width: 991px) { header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu .offsetWidth{ left: -100%; margin-top: -43px; z-index: 9; } .last__sub-menu.offsetWidth, .sub-menu_to-right.offsetWidth{ right: 0!important; left: unset!important; } .last__sub-menu.offsetWidth .sub-menu, .sub-menu_to-right.offsetWidth .sub-menu { left: -100%!important; } } /**/ header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children a { text-align: left; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children a:hover { margin-top: 0; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.line { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; -moz-transition: all 0.3s; -ms-transition: all 0.3s; -o-transition: all 0.3s; transition: all 0.3s; position: absolute; bottom: 11px; left: 0; height: 0px; pointer-events: none; border: 1px solid #4285f4; background: #4285f4; -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1); -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1.22); transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1.22); opacity: 0; display: block; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li:hover > a { color: #4285f4; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li:hover > a::before { -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotate(-45deg); -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotate(-45deg); -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotate(-45deg); transform: translateX(5px) rotate(-45deg); width: 10px; right: 12px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li:hover > a::after { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -o-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg); width: 10px; right: 7px; } header .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li:hover.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu { display: block; } header .hamburger-menu { display: none; } header.small::before { box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.2); height: 100%; } header.small .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::before, header.small .desk-menu .menu-container .menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after { background-color: #4e4e4e; } header.small .desk-menu .logo-adn { margin-top: 14px; } header.small .desk-menu .logo-adn a { background-image: url("../img/empresa-1-logo.svg"); height: 30px; width: 140px; } header.small .desk-menu .box-menu { padding: 0; } header.small .desk-menu .box-menu ul li a { color: #4e4e4e; } /*A plus icon*/ .plus-icon { height: 32px; width: 32px; position: relative; } .plus-icon::before, .plus-icon::after { content: " "; width: 32px; height: 6px; background-color: #000; display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(.42, 0, .58, 1); opacity: 1; border-radius: 2px; } .plus-icon::before { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg); } .plus-icon::after { transform: translate(-50%, -50%); } .plus-icon.expanded::before { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); } .plus-icon.expanded::after { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="over-menu"></div>
  <div id="wrap">
   <header class="header" id="header-sroll">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="desk-menu">

        <nav class="box-menu">
         <div class="menu-container">

          <div class="menu-header-container">
           <ul id="cd-primary-nav" class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="h#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#">Третий пункт</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Второй уровень</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                  <a href="#">Третий уровень</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Пункт третего уровня</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu_to-right">
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contact menu-item ">
             <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
            </li>
            <!-- a plus -->
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#"><b>+</b></a> <!-- <i class="plus-icon"></i> -->
             <ul class="sub-menu last__sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Второй уровень</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                  <a href="#">Третий уровень</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Пункт третего уровня</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                   </li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
               <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- end a plus -->
            <li class="line"></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
        </nav>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
  </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Не совсем в тему, но всё же - если вложенность меню на сайте 3+, то тут присутствует проблема с архитектурой. Этого не любят ни пользователи, ни поисковеки. К тому же вот ещё проблемы с дизайном.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, меню на три уровня делаю впервые, по этому буду рад если подскажите, как поправить архитектуру для третьего уровня, код по стилям предоставлен не весь по этому на дизайн не стоит обращать внимания + он не доделан